# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, bubble-sort

i write a program about customer registiriation. i saved customer inf. to txt file and i saved depts of customers in the access database.
I want to rank the borrowers from small to large or large to small.So, i transfered of data in the debt column and use with bubble sort. but I'm getting the error I specified in the title.how to fix it?

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand();

       conn.Open();


        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" SELECT  RemainingDept FROM Dept_Tbl  ", conn);

        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<string> liste = new List<string>();
        List<string> liste1 = new List<string>();
        while ((dr.Read()))
        {

            liste.Add(dr["RemainingDept"].ToString());

        }


        int[] B;
        string[] A = liste.ToArray();

        B = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(A, int.Parse);

        int tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i <A.Length ; i++)
        {
            for (int j=A.Length-1; j>i; j++)
            {
                if (B[j - 1] > B[j])
                {
                    tmp = B[j - 1];
                    B[j - 1] = B[j];
                    B[j] = tmp;
                listBox3.Items.Add(tmp.ToString());
                }
            }

        }

        conn.Close();
    }
} 

    }
```

[image]

Comment: There is some logic error at `for (int j=A.Length-1; j>i; j++)` as `j` will grow up forever, so eventually the index got out of array range

Comment: yes, u r right, when i make "for (int j=A.Length-1; j>i; j--) " it doesnt error. But it is sorting like " 40 60 60 "  .  it must   "20 40 60 ". @Magnetron

Comment: Are you sure that's not your input data? Because I just tested here and it worked

Comment: The very first thing to do is reduce this to a [mcve] which doesn't need any UI or database access.

Comment: How are you checking the sorting? Because the line `listBox3.Items.Add(tmp.ToString());` doesn't store the final array, but only intermediate steps. If you want to see the result, you must put another for loop after the sorting to add the itens to the listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error in the for loop, as `j` will grow up forever. Also, it may be good to change `A.Length` to `B.Length`, although they have the same size, you're operating on B not A, so this make the code more understandable. Here is the code with an example:

```
string[] A = new string[]{"60","120","10","40","80","20"};
int[] B = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(A, int.Parse);

int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < B.Length ; i++)
{
    for (int j = B.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        if (B[j - 1] > B[j])
        {
            tmp = B[j - 1];
            B[j - 1] = B[j];
            B[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
// Results in 10,20,40,60,80,120
```

Edit: If you want `listBox3` to contain the sorted array, you must put after the sorting loop, like this :

```
listBox3.Items.Clear(); //Use this line if you need to clear the contents.
for(int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(B[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works.
i have one more question. i sorting and see the listbox but i want to sorting  depts with customer ıd .İ mean, i wanna see that in listbox, id s + sorted depts

Comment: @bzkl_makiko I didn't quiet understood, but as this is another issue, I suggest opening another question (before you post, check Jon Skeet comment to your question, so you can post a better quality question next time).